# ODBC "Invalid connection string" when trying to connect to Azure SQL Server from Mac Excel 2016

Tags: sql-server, excel, macos, azure, azure-sql-database

I'm trying to use an Azure SQL database as a data source in Microsoft Excel 2016 for Mac as outlined in [this blog](https://blogs.office.com/en-us/2015/08/20/working-with-external-data-in-excel-2016-for-mac/).

Network-wise, on the server I have allowed connections for my IP range and I did confirm that my local firewall was disabled and the necessary port (1433) is open and available.

I've also confirmed that I can connect successfully using the connection string parameters from the Azure dashboard via from Excel on a Windows machine.

I'm able to connect and successfully query the database from the command line using sql-cli and the same parameters that I'm trying to use in Excel, so I feel like this issue is something in how I'm formatting the [connection details in the Excel dialogue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCmrC.png).

At first, of course, I used the connection parameters as listed in the Azure SQL portal. In response, I get a not very useful error dialogue:

[ODBC] (10360) Invalid connection string

Things I've tried:

- server name followed by comma and port number
- server name by itself
- user name alone
- user name with '@[domain]'
- all variations of the above

Am I somehow formatting the connection details wrong or am I missing some other element?

Comment: User name is a Azure AD user?

Comment: I'm being told that it is.

Comment: The connection details seem alright.

Comment: @J.Mayhugh No, you could not use Azure AD user on MAc, try Administrator user.

Comment: @J.Mayhugh Using server admin not using a Azure AD user. Like this: https://imgur.com/a/eH1NQ

Comment: Yes, I'm using the server admin user account....(so I guess it wasn't the Azure AD user?) Sorry, I'm really not familiar with active directory and also new to the Azure platform.